Which closed/deleted/locked ID questions should be reopened/undeleted/unlocked?
This week, CM JNat posed the following question in comments on a post about restoring the ID content that was obliterated during the ID ban:

should the unlocking, undeleting, and reopening be applied to all questions that fall under that criteria, or are there additional criteria (date, score, etc.) that should be taken into consideration here?

In the ensuing discussion, two proposals were put forward:

I believe that any question previously closed for being an identification question should be unlocked, reopened, and undeleted. -- galacticninja


I would strongly advise to apply this only to the questions that were mass-closed/deleted/locked during the ID ban in '15 for now. -- NapoleonWilson

These two different proposals both have their pros and cons, but it's not easy to discuss them deeply in comments, nor to get an idea of consensus as comments can only be upvoted and not downvoted. In the interests of keeping things constructive (as reminded by CM BellaBlue), I've branched this discussion out into a new meta question, where different proposals can be posted as answers and voted upon, in order that there can (hopefully) be a clear consensus for CMs to implement before the end of the year. (The second half of this answer was edited in after it had already got upvoted, so that doesn't count as consensus for galacticninja's proposal.)
Given that older ID questions are to be restored, which set of questions should this apply to, and what level of restoration (reopening/undeleting/unlocking) should be done?
As a point of order: unlocking can only be done with diamond powers (mods/CMs); undeleting can be done by high-rep users unless the post was diamond-deleted, in which case it can only be done with diamond powers; reopening can be done by high-rep users as long as the question is unlocked. These facts may affect which of these acts should be requested from CMs in an en-masse operation.

We appreciate all opinions, but let’s aim for suggestions beyond requesting 'all ID questions ever.' This could unintentionally include posts that were incorrectly tagged as identification questions, including spam, explicit content, or general recommendations. Let’s focus on ideas that help maintain quality and relevance.

@AnkitSharma - In the absence of any raw data from you on this, it's hard to see why "All ID questions ever" is a bad idea. Is there a lot of spam that was tagged with ID tags? If so, how many?

@Valorum It’s honestly surprising that, as such a long-time user, you’ve somehow never encountered a single low-quality ID question or one that's actually spam disguised as an ID request. Just wondering!

@AnkitSharma - Anecdote isn't data. I've seen a few over the last decade, but if that's what you're basing it on, then the number is microscopic.

@Valorum The numbers would definitely be higher, but getting them would take time to write queries—especially with deleted questions. And then there’s the issue of fetching close reasons and flags... not sure if that's even possible without some serious backend access!

Honestly, I would've thought that "don't undelete spam/explicit content" goes without saying.

@F1Krazy - The problem is that 'things that go without saying' sometimes get missed. Better to say them.

@F1Krazy slipups happens all the time. One wrong button clicked and now you have mess worth weeks to clean or intitiate another request to staff and wait for 4-6 weeks.

Just to provide some context: my original feature request meta post from two months ago was marked just a few days ago as "status-planned" by Stack Exchange staff. That request did not specify limiting restoration to only the 2018 ID purge questions. It’s worth noting that this opposition only emerged after the staff approved the request, despite users having had two months to voice any concerns.

@galacticninja Maybe actually discussing things through properly before calling SE to do "something on some kind of ID questions, I guess" could be a reasonable idea for once. Then people aren't surprised that SE doesn't agree with their personal common sense. ;-) You say the request did not specify a limitation, nor did it specify no limitation. I say that limitation is common sense, you obviously disagree. Yet Rand was the only one actually inciting the necessary discussion. We can't hold your hands all the time, voting to bring back ID questions doesn't magically make things happen.

@NapoleonWilson You make a fair point about proper discussion. Ironically, this thorough discussion was missing during the 2018 ID purge that created our current predicament. ☺ What I’m puzzled about is why these objections are coming only now, at the last minute, after staff approved implementation, when my feature request was open for feedback and discussion for over two months. And just to be clear—I do support some limitations, specifically excluding questions flagged for spam/abuse or explicit content, as Valorum suggested.

@galacticninja I figure you see that people waking up to a discussion afterwards is a thing that exists. Gotta make the best of the meta activity you can get, I'm afraid. ;-) As to me personally, I kind of phased out of this whole mess once I didn't have to care about it anymore. But when JNat came and said "so...you want me to undelete every ID question ever or what?", it triggered some few remaining alarm bells. ;-) As to others, like e.g. Rand and also poor JNat, they probably just didn't have an all too clear idea on what exactly to undelete and reopen. Therefore this question.

@galacticninja A general observation I make with your specific meta questions (and make no mistake, your active engagement on meta and the effort you put into it is laudable), is that they all too often come at the scene with a specific request rather than a discussion what to actually do. I know you think the community has a very firm idea of what exactly to do with ID questions and has had it for years and now that the vote is through, they obviously agree with all your points. Just that's not actually the case...

...You have to understand that the vote to allow identification questions back on the site again is as fuzzy as it gets. There is a lot unclear about the details of how this is supposed to proceed and these have to be hashed out somehow, without you already knowing that everyone wants every single question back and wanted that since 2018. There is a fine line between being proactive and feeling entitled.

It turns out there were only 684 mod-deleted ID questions after the 2018 ID ban, which is a small number compared to the 3,726 questions deleted during the ban. That seems manageable for the community to review. Since only mods can undelete these posts, users can’t search for deleted questions unless they’re their own, and users below 10K rep can’t view deleted questions at all; restoring them would give the community a chance to evaluate them instead of relying solely on the mods’ discretion.

Thank you for bringing this up. In line with my earlier comment, I would strongly advise to first concentrate this automated effort on the questions that were cleaned up in a similar automated fashion by SE when the ban was put in place, specifically the two concerted cleanup efforts in February 2018. However, it doesn't need to stop there. But this whole problem is rather multifaceted.

So first of all, of course all the questions locked during that process, deleted or not, can be unlocked, which also opens them up for community moderation again. There is really no reason to keep them locked anymore.

Then all the questions not deleted during that cleanup phase could supposedly be reopened automatically, since the idea back then was to keep them undeleted precisely because they had sufficiently high quality and garnered satisfying answers.

I suppose the questions deleted during that process could also be undeleted (but not reopened...yet). It might be worth undeleting only the ones with positive scores, but if we assume that at the moment of enacting the 2018 cleanup process the questions remaining on the site were good enough for it when ID was tolerated and the rest was deleted earlier anyway, then I suppose they can as well all be undeleted.

Then it already gets tricky. Part of bringing ID questions back was doing so under some form of quality regulation. Now while I see the community is indeed exercising their community moderation tools on the newly asked ID question, there doesn't seem to be much of a codified standard as to which questions are okay and which aren't (which is admittedly hard to find, we knew that already). Under this situation, it's not entirely clear if all the questions should be reopened.
However, this problem is alleviated a bit due to the fact that we also had quality moderation back then. So similar to the deleted questions, we can assume that at the point of enacting the ID question ban, the ones not closed yet were supposedly okay to remain open and might thus also be okay to remain open under whatever current quality standards now.


So to sum this up, I think it would be a good idea to first unlock all the ID questions locked during the past cleanup process. Then definitely reopen all the undeleted ones and at least undelete all the deleted ones. And I guess it would even be reasonable to reopen all the formerly deleted ones, too. So basically just
undo the two cleanup events from February 2018 wholesale, but only on these specific questions...for now.

Then we get to the questions asked after ID questions had been ruled off-topic. Now there could of course have been asked a lot of questions that could be fine under the current quality standards, but there could also have been a lot of bad questions. I would hesitate with injudiciously reopening all the questions closed as ID questions after the topic ban. This does require some genuine judgment and the users willing to engage in this process are already doing that. The questions aren't locked and users have voted to undelete and reopen them in the past.
I do think there could be possibilities to reopen these questions in some kind of controlled automated fashion, but I'd rather you tackle this problem at a later point once you're all clearer on which questions you actually want to see as identification questions. Fortunately, those aren't actually that many questions because the ban was rather effective at putting a halt to the very steady influx of identification questions, so those should be manageable to actually moderate with some proper human judgement. And luckily none of these questions actually run away. Let's face it, most of the people asking these are never going to return and those are often the only people actually helped by answering these questions. Noone dies from putting in some actual work and effort (and thus time) into reopening the proper questions. (Of course this puts up the question what the point of resurrecting all these dead questions actually is anyway, but for the sake of the discussion, I'll try not to ask that ;-)).

And this brings us to the danger in this and why I would strongly advise you to
not to do anything to the questions closed/deleted before the ID ban (or god beware, all the questions tagged identify-this-...).
This community has spent years of work and effort in maintaining this site and cleaning up unwelcome questions. Identification questions have always been a major part of these moderation efforts even when they were still on-topic. The community has come to the conclusion to make these questions on-topic again and we should respect that, together with bringing back some of the past good questions that were inappropriate merely because of falling afoul of that topic ban. However, injudiciously resurrecting all these questions that the site spent over a decade on moderating and cleaning up would be disrespecting and trashing all that work, which is a terrible mistake I implore you not to make out of some reactionary idea that you need to bring back all the ID questions now. Noone, neither god nor the community, can and will sort these out again after this decade of site maintenance has been destroyed. These questions had their chance (they were on-topic back then afterall) and they failed.

I'd like to also make some general remarks on this. As I said earlier, the community has decided to bring these questions back, but it's clear they remain (and will likely remain) a controversial issue and we are far from the community screaming in unison to suddenly undelete and reopen all the terrible ID questions we moderated over the course of the last 13 years. And I hope even the staunchest ID-proponents realize that trashing over a decade of site maintenance is not a good idea.
At the end of the day, we also have to accept the fact that site scope is a living and developing thing, which the reverted ID ban is a good example for. Throughout the history of the site we have questions which were fine in the past but wouldn't survive nowaways if asked anew, or which have been closed as off-topic but would be fine today. Not all of these past questions can (or even should) receive new treatment whenever site scope changes. We can do our best to adapt to new developments in site scope and treat questions coherently, but we neither can nor should rewrite history. In the same way we didn't delete every single ID question when the ban was put in place, we also have to live with the fact that a few good questions that might be okay to ask today might haven gotten lost to time. Maybe if the askers actually still care about them, they'll reask them. If not, we'll get new ones, bet sure we will.
As a personal anecdote, throughout the history of the site I always had a big staple of favourited questions that I feel had been closed unfairly and could be turned into great on-topic questions. And some of them I did manage to bring around, but others I also had to unfavourite, accepting the fact that I might not ever find the time to bring them back or might fail at it. The good thing is, other new great questions took their place. That isn't to say "forget about it, the ID questions are lost forever", but merely that you can't bring back all of them and trying to do so in some broad-stroked automated way is very dangerous and quite simply not actually what the community signed up for when saying that ID questions are on-topic again.
As a closing...closing remark, I was, and still am, rather happy to have mostly disengaged from the moderation and maintenance of this site. I have, however, not entirely given up on it and turned its back towards it. I can't stop anyone from destroying over a decade of the work and effort put into the site and part of stepping down from the moderator position was not having to care about this anymore. I do, however, care enough to at least engage this meta discussion and am glad you brought it up, since it is an important decision that shouldn't be let to fall entirely to disregard or overreaction.

Thank you for this well-thought-out answer sharing your experience based on having moderated this stuff for many years including through the banning process. One question (not sure if you can answer this or if it would require current diamond access): if we undeleted (but not reopened) all questions closed as ID since the ID ban went into effect, how much work would it be to go through them all? I.e. (1) are they all tagged in a way so that they could be easily listed by a simple search? (2) how many of them are there, few enough to list in a single meta post and curate, or way too many?

I've seen several well-detailed, good-quality ID questions that a single moderator deleted immediately after closing them, following the 2018 ID question purge. Many of these questions were posted just this year. Our community has successfully undeleted and reopened some of these moderator deleted questions. Some of these questions have even received correct answers—opportunities that would have been permanently lost had the questions remained deleted. Should these questions remain deleted despite being adequately detailed and perfectly answerable?

@galacticninja I think I have made it rather clear in my answer that they probably shouldn't. What's your point?

@NapoleonWilson I'm concerned about the dozens, if not hundreds, of good-quality, well-detailed ID questions that were deleted by unilateral moderator action after the 2018 ID purge. Since you were involved in many, if not most, of those deletions, wouldn't it make more sense to give the community a chance to review and restore the ones that meet our current standards? Many of those adequately detailed questions could benefit the community and increase site activity.

I really can't see where I'm denying anyone that chance. Have you actually read my answer? Which standards, though?

@NapoleonWilson You're suggesting delaying their restoration. The community has been successfully moderating ID questions for 5 months now — we are clear on what ID questions we want to see. The bigger issue is that deleted questions can't be searched or reviewed by regular users. Wouldn't it make more sense to undelete them and let the community evaluate each one on its merits? This seems more productive than unnecessarily delaying for some indefinite period when we're supposedly "clearer" on our standards.

@NapoleonWilson "Which standards, though?" The community's standards. The standards our community has been applying to ID questions over the past 5 months. We've developed clear patterns in what we consider acceptable and what we don't.

@galacticninja What are those standards/patterns then? I haven't been very active on this site in recent months, so I don't know. I've been under the impression that no consensus has been reached yet on which ID questions to close or leave open since their reintroduction, so please enlighten me.

@Randal'Thor From what I've observed over these past months, the community has developed a fairly consistent approach. ID questions typically only get closed as "needs details or clarity" when the provided details are too vague to identify a single movie/show, or when the description is so broad it could match several different movies/shows. Most ID questions stay open, which tells me the community isn't looking to be overly strict about detail requirements.

@gal That's a good approach to take, IMHO (like how we handle "what am I"-type riddles at [puzzling.se]) but a bit worrying to think about going through thousands of questions to apply those standards, if everything from 2018-24 gets undeleted for the community to vote on. Because it's not a test that can be applied easily by anyone - it takes careful consideration and experience to judge whether an ID question has a unique answer or not. I wonder if there's any way to know how many (non-spam/abusive) ID questions were deleted in those 6 years - are we talking hundreds, thousands, ... ?

@Randal'Thor I think the simplest approach would be to undelete these questions and let the community review them. The alternative—keeping them deleted and expecting users to somehow find and undelete them—is much more complicated (Occam's Razor) since we can't even search deleted posts that aren't our own, and there's no undelete review queue. I believe we're likely talking about dozens or maybe a few hundreds of unilateral mod-deleted ID questions (not counting Roomba deletions or posts closed for other reasons). (cont...)

@Randal'Thor The mods could confirm the exact number, but even if it's a few hundreds, that seems quite manageable for our community to review, especially since some would likely get Roomba'd anyway.

@Randal'Thor "I wonder if there's any way to know how many (non-spam/abusive) ID questions were deleted in those 6 years - are we talking hundreds, thousands, ... ?" I asked about it on meta: How many ID questions were deleted by a moderator since the February 2018 ID question mass deletion?

@NapoleonWilson There's a significant practical concern with delaying the restoration of mod-deleted ID questions from after the 2018 purge. Since only moderators can undelete these posts, and users can't even search for deleted questions except their own, the community is effectively locked out of the review process. With no undelete review queue and only one active mod handling ID restoration flags, this essentially prevents any meaningful community involvement in reviewing these posts.

Regarding the second section of your answer (questions deleted during the period of the full ban on ID) - now that JNat has given us a figure of ~700 questions and we can grasp the scope of the issue, what do you think about unlocking and undeleting (but not reopening) those questions? Closures can always be reversed by the community if they see fit, including mod-closures, but mod-deletions can't be. Let's at least make them visible to people and then decide about reopening or not? Roomba will clear them up after a while if they don't get reopened.

AnkitSharma, in his comment above, has rightly identified that a blanket undeletion of every single question that was originally tagged with [identify-this-*], without giving any regard to the reason why it was deleted, could lead to undesirable consequences.
I therefore propose that we modify GalacticNinja's proposal to take these concerns into account;

I believe that any question previously closed for being an identification question should be unlocked, reopened, and undeleted [unless it was deleted with a spam flag or where a flag was raised to a moderator for explicit content.]

Hopefully, this will restore the maximum number of deleted ID questions, while simultaneously rejecting those (presumably few) bad apples before they ever get seen by the community.

What about all those one-liners where the user never returns, racks up a dozen downvotes, and ignores any input?

@AnkitSharma - It would appear that undeleted questions that are heavily underwater are only safe from the roomba for a short period, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359643/if-a-roomba-deleted-question-gets-undeleted-please-either-reset-the-timer-or. They'd also not appear on the front page, so I'm not sure what the problem would be.,

@AnkitSharma "What about all those one-liners where the user never returns, racks up a dozen downvotes…" Roomba—the Community user's automated cleanup scripts—auto-deletes questions with zero or negative scores, so it shouldn’t be an issue.

@galacticninja - Plus a lot of those are probably answerable. People are very quick to downvote a question as unanswerable merely because it's concise.

@Valorum Just because one person know the answer doesn't means it's good quality. I see sparkling vampire tell me which movie is not a good question but obviosuly you can answer it saying twilight.

@AnkitSharma - Sure, and if that's the answer, OP can accept it and we can all move on with our lives. If they don't accept it, perhaps they can be persuaded to give us more detail. But if their question is insta-downvoted and then closed, they'll probably just write us off as a shitty place to post their questions and go elsewhere, never to return.

@Valorum So you support badly written ID if you can answer them? That's your point?

@AnkitSharma - I support encouraging the poster to improve their questions, yes. That's literally the purpose of SE. You appear to support driving them away.

This is a sensible approach. No need to throw the baby out with the bathwater—we can remove the problematic content while preserving the worthwhile questions. Let's keep the baby and throw out only the bathwater.

@galacticninja As of now, is there any consensus on what's baby and what's bathwater? That is to say, has the community agreed which ID questions should be closed under current standards? I haven't been following this issue all that closely, but it seems that's something necessary to consider before undeleting thousands of questions and then re-deleting some of them.

@Randal'Thor The community can handle this through normal review processes. We should undelete everything except those flagged as spam/abusive/explicit content, as suggested by Valorum here, then let the automated Roomba system remove low-quality (zero/negative score) posts and let community members vote on any borderline cases. This makes more sense than leaving dozens, if not hundreds, of mod-deleted (not Roomba/community-deleted) ID questions permanently hidden from community review.

From these two proposals, I very much prefer what NapoleonWilson said.
Why? While identification questions may not be outright banned, there are still reasons to close some of them, which aren't spam flag, or explicit content. Perhaps biggest reason is that a lot of them simply lack enough detail to answer them. Other than that some can be also very low quality - terribly written. Lots of unclear or even VLQ questions that were also identifications got closed with identification reason. Such questions should stay deleted.

Low quality questions will automatically get swept away by the roomba. All this proposal does is keep perfectly good questions locked and deleted.

What about the many good-quality, well-detailed ID questions (perhaps dozens, if not hundreds) that moderators deleted after the 2018 ID question purge? Should they remain deleted despite being adequately detailed and perfectly answerable?

Roomba isn't nearly as good in cleaning as you think, or perhaps voting isn't. I'm pretty sure there were lots of unanswerable identify questions with a +2 score that would never be deleted by roomba, or with +1 and two comments, or...

@Mithoron Why not let the community handle the few posts that might slip past Roomba? Since the 2018 ID purge, moderators have deleted many identification questions that the community would likely want to see undeleted and reopened. This approach would allow the community as a whole—not individual moderators—to decide what stays. Since heavily downvoted posts are hidden from the site feed anyway, concerns about numerous low-quality questions returning seem overblown.

I agree with @Valorum's suggestion that we should unlock, reopen, and undelete all questions previously closed for being ID questions, with the exception of those deleted due to spam flags or those flagged for explicit content.
This comprehensive approach makes more sense than keeping several potentially valuable questions deleted due to concerns about a small number of problematic posts.
Some moderators have expressed concerns about restoring low-quality, heavily downvoted content. However, SE sites already have a system in place to handle such content. The Community user's automated cleanup scripts (AKA Roomba) automatically remove questions with zero or negative scores that meet specific deletion criteria. These scripts will automatically re-delete any restored questions that don't meet quality standards.
My observation of ID questions has revealed that most, if not all, moderator-deleted (not Roomba-deleted) ID questions (post-2018 ID purge) were actually good questions with enough detail that would likely receive community support today.
In fact, our community has successfully undeleted and reopened several previously closed and moderator-deleted ID questions. Some of the undeleted questions have even received correct answers; opportunities that would have been permanently lost had the questions remained deleted.
The community currently can't vote to undelete nor search for mod-deleted questions, limiting community review.
There's a significant practical concern with not restoring mod-deleted ID questions from after the 2018 purge. Since only moderators can undelete these moderator-deleted posts, and users can't even search for deleted questions except their own, the community is effectively locked out of the review process. With no undelete review queue and only one active mod handling ID restoration flags, this essentially prevents any meaningful community involvement in reviewing these posts.
To illustrate the value of restoration, here are some ID questions I managed to bookmark and follow before their deletion by a moderator. (This was before SE adjusted the undeletion logic to take into account whether delete voters were moderators at the time of question deletion, so posts deleted by former moderators now cannot be undeleted by the community.)
These questions were later successfully undeleted, reopened, and received upvoted, likely correct answers, demonstrating our community's interest in preserving such content. Note that these examples are separate from the 2018 ID purge, and I only began monitoring these deletions in June 2024. There are likely many more similar cases from the 6-year period between the 2018 ID purge and when I began monitoring that merit restoration.

Help ID a film about an African American scientist recounting her time in a secret research facility while wearing a white mask
Movie with a man with a Chinese queue hairstyle riding a bike with a child in front and a woman in the back, all smiling
Animation featuring DC's Adam Strange saving planet Rann from a solar-powered war machine

If any problematic posts do get restored, and get past Roomba, our community (rather than a single moderator) can evaluate them through the standard review process. The benefits—recovering useful content and increasing site activity and engagement—significantly outweigh any possible drawbacks.

Exactly this. The fact that community moderation will experience a small and easily managed uptick for a few days is a very small price to pay for getting back one of the site's most popular features, at a time when engagement is at its lowest ebb since the site graduated.

Having a few low-quality ID questions near the front page closed as "needing details" will likely also clarify what constitutes a good ID question, and we get a clearer idea of any grey area that might exist, which we can then address again more targeted here on the meta page.
